# Web API Core 3.0 Logging HttpRequest Body as custom class object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

I am intercepting HTTP request using custom middleware and I want to Log request and response to .json file using NLog.
The problem occurs when I want to **deserialize Request/Response body from string to custom class object** and then POST/PUT/DELETE methods are not working.

> Postman on POST method throws: *500 Internal Server Error*
>
> Angular app on POST method throws: *Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myValidEndpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

If I Log request/response body as a string every http method works fine. 
Here's the code:

**Program.cs**

```
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            LogManager.LoadConfiguration(String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/nlog.config"));
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public HttpConfiguration Config { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IDrzavaService, DrzavaService>();
            services.AddTransient<IGradService, GradService>();
            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<DrzavedbContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DrzaveConnection")))
                .AddUnitOfWork<DrzavedbContext>();
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });

        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMyMiddleware();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });


        }
    }
```

**nlog.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="./GlobalErrorHandlingLogs/internal_logs/internallog.txt">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target name="ExceptionMiddleware" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="./../../../GlobalErrorHandlingLogs/logs/${shortdate}_logfile.txt"
            layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"/>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="AutoFlushWrapper">
      <target name="RequestLoggingMiddleware" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="./../../../HttpRequestHandlingLogs/logs/${shortdate}_HttpLog.json">
        <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" >
          <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
          <attribute name="eventProperties" encode="false">
            <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="5"/>
          </attribute>
        </layout>
      </target>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="ExceptionMiddleware" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" maxlevel="Info" writeTo="RequestLoggingMiddleware" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**RequestLoggingMiddleware.cs**

```
public class RequestLoggingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly Logger _logger;
        private readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _recyclableMemoryStreamManager;
        Stopwatch _stopwatch;

        public RequestLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            _recyclableMemoryStreamManager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            await LogRequest(context);
            await LogResponse(context);
        }


        private async Task LogRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            context.Request.Headers.Add("X-Request-Guid", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            await using var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
            await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
            string bodyString = ReadStreamInChunks(requestStream);
            List<BodyItem> body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BodyItem>>(bodyString);

            RequestModel requestModel = new RequestModel()
            {
                requestStart = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"),
                method = context.Request.Method,
                schema = context.Request.Scheme,
                host = context.Request.Host.ToString(),
                path = context.Request.Path,
                requestBody = body,
                requestGuid = context.Request.Headers["X-Request-Guid"]
            };

            _logger.Info("{request}", requestModel);


            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        }

        private static string ReadStreamInChunks(Stream stream)
        {
            const int readChunkBufferLength = 4096;
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using var textWriter = new StringWriter();
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var readChunk = new char[readChunkBufferLength];
            int readChunkLength;
            do
            {
                readChunkLength = reader.ReadBlock(readChunk, 0, readChunkBufferLength);
                textWriter.Write(readChunk, 0, readChunkLength);
            } while (readChunkLength > 0);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }

        private async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Request-Guid", context.Request.Headers["X-Request-Guid"].ToString());
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
            await using var responseBody = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
            context.Response.Body = responseBody;
            await _next(context);
            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string bodyStream = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            List<BodyItem> body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BodyItem>>(bodyStream);

            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);


            ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel()
            {
                requestEnd = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"),
                responseBody = body,
                responseGuid = context.Response.Headers["X-Request-Guid"],
                statusCode = context.Response.StatusCode.ToString(),
                requestDuration = _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
            };

            _logger.Info("{response}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseModel));

            await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
        }
    }

    public static class MyMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<RequestLoggingMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

**BodyItem.cs**

```
[JsonObject]
    class BodyItem
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public int? population { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public int? countryId{ get; set; }
    }
```

**RequestModel.cs**

```
class RequestModel
    {
        public string requestStart { get; set; }
        public string method { get; set; }
        public string schema { get; set; }
        public string host { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public List<BodyItem> requestBody { get; set; }
        public string requestGuid { get; set; }
    }
```

**ResponseModel.cs**

```
class ResponseModel
    {
        public string requestEnd { get; set; }
        public List<BodyItem> responseBody { get; set; }
        public string responseGuid { get; set; }
        public string statusCode { get; set; }
        public float requestDuration { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `Postman on POST method throws: 500 Internal Server Error` Have you tried to debug the code and check which code snippet cause exception/error in your custom Middleware

Comment: @Fei Han
 Yes. Deserializing request/response body string to custom class object.

`List<BodyItem> body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BodyItem>>(bodyString);`

Problem happens on conversion, even when I don't use this variable in my code and use string to represent the body.
But if I comment this line everything works fine.

Comment: `List<BodyItem> body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BodyItem>>(bodyString);` If the data from request body can not be deserialized to **`List<BodyItem>`** object, it will cause error. Are you sure that all request body sent by API consumer should be deserialized to **`List<BodyItem>`** object? Perhaps you may need to perform different code logic to deserialize to different custom class object based on **`context.Request.Path`**.

Comment: Thank you sir, I managed to understand the problem with your hint.
The problem occured when I'm  was trying to deserialize **one** object to **list** of objects in **response**. That's why GET  response worked because it has more objects to deserialize, but POST method sends one object!!
Now I have to just chech how many objects do I have in my response body and build logic accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem occurs when I want to deserialize Request/Response body from string to custom class object and then POST/PUT/DELETE methods are not working.

For above issue, as we discussed in comments, the data from request body sent by API consumer (or from response body) may not always be able to deserialized to List object, so it might cause error within your custom middleware code logic.

And to fix it, you can build additional code logic to check request path etc to to deserialize to different custom class object.

```
private async Task LogRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // check context.Request.Path
    // or context.Request.Method etc 
    // perform different code logic to deserialize to different custom class object

    if (context.Request.Path.ToString() == "/api/{your_controller_name}/{action_name}")
    {
        // code logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Once again thank you, I made it this way:

`Object body;
            if (bodyString != string.Empty)
            {
                body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bodyString);
            }
            else
            {
                body = new JObject();
            }`

Comment: You can build logic based on your actual sceanrio and requirement.